# Blinking of a certain section of image in beamer

Tags: pdftex, tikz-styles

I have drawn an image in latex using tikz as given by the code below. The image generated via the below code comprises of a  rectangular block having a text E(s) written inside it. I want to make this rectangular box along with the text inside it to blink and shine brightly (scintillating). How can I do it?

```
\documentclass[compress, xcolor=table, usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \begin{document}

\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        
\begin{frame}{Figure}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,235); %set diagram left start at 0, and has 
height of 235

%Rounded Rect [id:dp22728745820859309] 
\draw   (134,66.75) .. controls (134,62.33) and (137.58,58.75) .. 
(142,58.75) -- (196,58.75) .. controls (200.42,58.75) and (204,62.33) .. 
(204,66.75) -- (204,90.75) .. controls (204,95.17) and (200.42,98.75) .. 
(196,98.75) -- (142,98.75) .. controls (137.58,98.75) and (134,95.17) .. 
(134,90.75) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp23074367111159821] 
\draw   (254,64.75) .. controls (254,60.33) and (257.58,56.75) .. 
(262,56.75) -- (316,56.75) .. controls (320.42,56.75) and (324,60.33) .. 
(324,64.75) -- (324,88.75) .. controls (324,93.17) and (320.42,96.75) .. 
(316,96.75) -- (262,96.75) .. controls (257.58,96.75) and (254,93.17) .. 
(254,88.75) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da3785057523496602] 
\draw    (205,77.75) -- (251.5,76.79) ;
\draw [shift={(253.5,76.75)}, rotate = 538.8199999999999] [color={rgb, 
    255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. 
controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and 
(6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;

%Shape: Circle [id:dp7405273795099738] 
\draw   (350,76.5) .. controls (350,66.7) and (357.95,58.75) .. 
(367.75,58.75) .. controls (377.55,58.75) and (385.5,66.7) .. (385.5,76.5) 
.. controls (385.5,86.3) and (377.55,94.25) .. (367.75,94.25) .. controls 
(357.95,94.25) and (350,86.3) .. (350,76.5) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da4768143479707079] 
\draw    (323.75,77) -- (349.25,77) ;
\draw [shift={(351.25,77)}, rotate = 180] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 
    0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) 
and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. 
(10.93,3.29)   ;

%Shape: Circle [id:dp9725542364076398] 
\draw   (70,78.5) .. controls (70,68.7) and (77.95,60.75) .. (87.75,60.75) 
.. controls (97.55,60.75) and (105.5,68.7) .. (105.5,78.5) .. controls 
(105.5,88.3) and (97.55,96.25) .. (87.75,96.25) .. controls (77.95,96.25) 
and (70,88.3) .. (70,78.5) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da10367925110615261] 
\draw    (105.5,78.5) -- (135.75,78.5) ;
\draw [shift={(137.75,78.5)}, rotate = 180] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; 
    green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls 
(6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) 
.. (10.93,3.29)   ;

%Straight Lines [id:da3384320385828452] 
\draw    (87.75,136) -- (341.75,136) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da9706282263267894] 
\draw    (341.75,136) -- (341.75,77) ;

%Straight Lines [id:da01968558683101662] 
\draw    (87.75,137) -- (87.75,96.25) ;



% Text Node
\draw (289,76.75) node  [align=left] {P(s)};
% Text Node
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: With the animate package it is possible to do this: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/animate

Comment: You show an article document. However, the title is on a beamer document. In the `beamer` class it is *not* necessary to load `animate`. Rather, `beamer` has its own means to do animations.

Comment: I have replaced it with beamer. Please tell me, how exactly can I do with the animate package

Comment: I have understood the scintillating effect, but how can I make the text P(s) to blink too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in the comment, a beamer document has its built-in tools for doing animations. You do not need the `animate` package here. If you compile

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\newcount\mymix
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{A scintillator}
\animate<2-22>
\animatevalue<1-21>{\mymix}{0}{20}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[circ/.style={circle,inner sep=3.2mm,draw},
 box/.style={draw,rounded corners=3pt,minimum width=16mm,minimum height=8mm},
 line width=0.75pt]
 \begin{scope}[start chain=going right,nodes={on chain,join},
    every join/.style={-stealth}]
  \node[circ](C1){};
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mixture}{10*ifthenelse(\the\mymix<11,\the\mymix,20-\the\mymix)}
  \node[box](B1){$\mathsf{C}(\mathsf{s})$};
  \node[box,fill=yellow!\mixture](B2){$\mathsf{P}(\mathsf{s})$};
  \node[circ](C2){};
 \end{scope}
 \path (B2.east) -- coordinate (aux)(C2.west) ;
 \draw[-stealth](aux) --++ (0,-1cm) -| (C1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and view it in full screen mode on Acrobat Reader, you will see

[image]

Notice that I used the opportunity to shorten your Ti*k*Z code, and I hope I selected the rectangle you wanted to scintillate. Of course, one can change the details of the animation. You can change the rate with `\transduration`.

However, you can of course use the `animate` package. Translating the above to a code that uses this package yields

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{A scintillator}
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{1}
  \multiframe{20}{it=0+1}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[circ/.style={circle,inner sep=3.2mm,draw},
   box/.style={draw,rounded corners=3pt,minimum width=16mm,minimum height=8mm},
   line width=0.75pt]
   \begin{scope}[start chain=going right,nodes={on chain,join},
      every join/.style={-stealth}]
    \node[circ](C1){};
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mixture}{10*ifthenelse(\it<11,\it,20-\it)}
    \node[box](B1){$\mathsf{C}(\mathsf{s})$};
    \node[box,fill=yellow!\mixture](B2){$\mathsf{P}(\mathsf{s})$};
    \node[circ](C2){};
   \end{scope}
   \path (B2.east) -- coordinate (aux)(C2.west) ;
   \draw[-stealth](aux) --++ (0,-1cm) -| (C1);
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{animateinline}  
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

In both cases I do not know what precisely you mean by scintillating, so you may have to adjust some parameters.

Comment: This is exactly what I meant by scintillating, however the first solution is showing 22 separate slides. Also, can I make the text P(s) to blink also?

Comment: @ShiS Yes, but when you put it in full screen mode in Acrobat Reader, these slides will animate automatically from slide 2 on. This is how `beamer`s built-in animations work (I am using them all the time, maybe not for loops like blinking but for most other purposes).