# Coloring a tikzpicture with the overlays in the beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, itemize, tikz-styles, bullets

The code show below gives a block diagram, comprising of two blocks P(s) and C(s). These two blocks are also given in a list as separate items and each appear after the click of mouse. To draw the attention of audience, I want that when the first bullet of P(s) comes in the first slide, the corresponding rounded rectangle showing P(s) in the block diagram should be colored. And, when the second bullet of C(s) comes, the rounded rectangle of C(s) in the block diagram should become colored. How can I achieve that?

```
\documentclass[compress, xcolor=table, usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
     \usepackage{tikz}
     \begin{document}

     \tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        
\begin{frame}{Figure}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,235); %set diagram left start at 0, and has 
height of 235

%Rounded Rect [id:dp22728745820859309] 
\draw   (134,66.75) .. controls (134,62.33) and (137.58,58.75) .. 
(142,58.75) -- (196,58.75) .. controls (200.42,58.75) and (204,62.33) .. 
(204,66.75) -- (204,90.75) .. controls (204,95.17) and (200.42,98.75) .. 
(196,98.75) -- (142,98.75) .. controls (137.58,98.75) and (134,95.17) .. 
(134,90.75) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp23074367111159821] 
\draw   (254,64.75) .. controls (254,60.33) and (257.58,56.75) .. 
(262,56.75) -- (316,56.75) .. controls (320.42,56.75) and (324,60.33) .. 
(324,64.75) -- (324,88.75) .. controls (324,93.17) and (320.42,96.75) .. 
(316,96.75) -- (262,96.75) .. controls (257.58,96.75) and (254,93.17) .. 
(254,88.75) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da3785057523496602] 
\draw    (205,77.75) -- (251.5,76.79) ;
\draw [shift={(253.5,76.75)}, rotate = 538.8199999999999] [color={rgb, 
    255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. 
controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and 
(6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;

%Shape: Circle [id:dp7405273795099738] 
\draw   (350,76.5) .. controls (350,66.7) and (357.95,58.75) .. 
(367.75,58.75) .. controls (377.55,58.75) and (385.5,66.7) .. (385.5,76.5) 
.. controls (385.5,86.3) and (377.55,94.25) .. (367.75,94.25) .. controls 
(357.95,94.25) and (350,86.3) .. (350,76.5) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da4768143479707079] 
\draw    (323.75,77) -- (349.25,77) ;
\draw [shift={(351.25,77)}, rotate = 180] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 
    0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) 
and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. 
(10.93,3.29)   ;

%Shape: Circle [id:dp9725542364076398] 
\draw   (70,78.5) .. controls (70,68.7) and (77.95,60.75) .. (87.75,60.75) 
.. controls (97.55,60.75) and (105.5,68.7) .. (105.5,78.5) .. controls 
(105.5,88.3) and (97.55,96.25) .. (87.75,96.25) .. controls (77.95,96.25) 
and (70,88.3) .. (70,78.5) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da10367925110615261] 
\draw    (105.5,78.5) -- (135.75,78.5) ;
\draw [shift={(137.75,78.5)}, rotate = 180] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; 
    green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls 
(6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) 
.. (10.93,3.29)   ;

%Straight Lines [id:da3384320385828452] 
\draw    (87.75,136) -- (341.75,136) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da9706282263267894] 
\draw    (341.75,136) -- (341.75,77) ;

%Straight Lines [id:da01968558683101662] 
\draw    (87.75,137) -- (87.75,96.25) ;



% Text Node
\draw (289,76.75) node  [align=left] {P(s)};
\draw (169,76.75) node  [align=left] {C(s)};
% Text Node
\end{tikzpicture}
    \beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}
\begin{itemize}
    \item P(s)
    \item C(s)
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: TikZ and beamer were both written by Till Tantau. He took care to make one compatible with the other. So all you have to do is use both `\pause` commands and add an overlay in the form `<3->` to the corresponding command that colors what you want in your code.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I admire your courage and patience in drawing step by step, rectangles and circles using bezier curves.

If you have been able to do this, you may be interested to know that TikZ has planned to do all these calculations automatically.

For this purpose TikZ has created what is called a `node`. A `node` is a circular, rectangular or other shape containing text.

The advantage of using nodes is that tikz intelligently draws arrows that go from one to the other. That is, the arrow goes from edge to edge and does not penetrate (unless asked) inside the `node`.

I took the liberty (and I apologize) to delete your very nice code by a shorter code that uses Tikz nodes. But I kept your dimensions in pt.

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator (free version)

```
\documentclass[compress, xcolor=table, usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
     \usepackage{tikz}
     \usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
     \begin{document}

     \tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}, %set default line width to 0.75pt        
     skip loop/.style={to path={--++(0,25pt) -| (\tikztotarget)}},
     filled/.style={draw,rectangle,minimum height=30pt,fill=yellow,minimum width=50pt,rounded corners},
     unfilled/.style={draw,rectangle,minimum height=30pt,minimum width=50pt,rounded corners},
     cercle/.style={draw,circle,minimum size=25pt}}
\begin{frame}{Figure}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]

\node[cercle](initial) at (80,78.5){};
\node[unfilled,right =of initial](second){C(s)};
\node[unfilled,right = 39pt of second](third){P(s)};
\node[cercle,right =21pt of third](terminal){};
\draw[->](initial)--(second)--(third)--(terminal);
\path[blue,->] (initial)edge[skip loop]($(third.east)!.5!(terminal.west)$);


\node<1>[filled]at(third){P(s)};
\node<2>[filled]at(second){C(s)};
\end{tikzpicture}
    %\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item P(s)
    \item C(s)
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: animation]

Comment: Thanks. I will use nodes from now om

Answer (score 1):

Let me essentially repeat my [earlier answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/518055/194703) here. Let me mention that there is a is the package `overlay-beamer-styles` which is precisely made for this situation. It spares you from overpainting things and prevents jumps. You only need to say

```
\node[box,highlight on=<1>](B1){$\mathsf{C}(\mathsf{s})$};
```

to highlight the `C` node on the first slide.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,overlay-beamer-styles}
\tikzset{highlight on/.style args={<#1>}{alt=<#1>{fill=yellow}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t] % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/518055/194703
\frametitle{A scintillator}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circ/.style={circle,inner sep=3.2mm,draw},
 box/.style={draw,rounded corners=3pt,minimum width=16mm,minimum height=8mm},
 line width=0.75pt]
 \begin{scope}[start chain=going right,nodes={on chain,join},
    every join/.style={-stealth}]
  \node[circ](C1){};
  \node[box,highlight on=<1>](B1){$\mathsf{C}(\mathsf{s})$};
  \node[box,highlight on=<2>](B2){$\mathsf{P}(\mathsf{s})$};
  \node[circ](C2){};
 \end{scope}
 \path (B2.east) -- coordinate (aux)(C2.west) ;
 \draw[-stealth](aux) --++ (0,-1cm) -| (C1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item P(s)
    \item C(s)
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]